# Is it possible to lock affinity of a MassTransit saga to a given consumer?

Tags: masstransit, saga

In a case where the steps of a saga relay on local resources (e.g, temp files) from previous steps, is it possible to force those steps to execute on a given consumer (say the one that fired the event which created the saga)?

I can get around this by creating a centralized file store location, but I am just curious if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. They aren't really designed with any sort of affinity. It's normally only really a problem if you are load balancing the consumers/sagas though. Is this the case?

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, there might be some options but we would need a little more detail. The mailing list might be better place to explore this a bit more: https://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss.

Comment: I'm brand new to MT, so I'm just trying to grasp at the concepts and how this all will work in practice, but I plan to run logical consumer instances across multiple machines (though I'm not sure at this point what is requires to do this successfully).  I'll stick with a shared data store for now, but if there are any other tips you can provide to ease this learning curve (e.g., what questions should I be asking?) any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Travis, I see some posts on the discussion list about load balancing, but the more recent ones around RabbitMQ make it seem like in a competing consumer scenario (with multiple instances of a logical process reading from a centralized queue instance) that things "just work".  Is this not the case/am I missing something?  I'm assuming load balancing as you mentioned refers more to spreading publishes across multiple queues, which each have their own set of consumers, is that correct, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, competing consumers (such as many machines reading from the same queue with the same service) works great for load balancing. And in that case I could see the need for affinity in the Saga. Otherwise, the saga is just in memory anyways. Doesn't need affinity, does it? I have a draft blog post about the load balancing options. Maybe I should finish it...

Comment: If you don't mind sending the draft my way, please do.  I do need to read more about sagas and think how I'll use them, but I think the cases that make sense won't need affinity but will be longer running, hence need persistence.

Comment: Bring it up on the mailing list, what you're trying to do, and there's a number of people can that help guide you.